# Make docker nginx forward an angular app requests to consume APIs through Unix domain socket

Tags: java, docker, api, nginx, unix-socket

I'm trying to interconnect two docker containers process using Unix domain socket creating a socket path in my host and sharing that volume in each container something like that:

in my docker-compose file

```
services: 
    my-ngixn-container:
         image: nginx:1.20.2-alpine
         container_name: my-ngixn-container
    ...
    volumes:
         - ${PWD}/env/mysocket.socket:/env/mysocket.socket  

    my-api-container:
         image: openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
         container_name: my-api-container
    ...
    volumes:
         - ${PWD}/env/mysocket.socket:/env/mysocket.socket
```

I want to make my angular app consume the API through the Unix domain socket, I suppose that I could set Nginx to forward all the requests through the Unix socket.

Comment: Typically in Docker you'd use a TCP socket for this instead.  It's much easier to set up (see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)) and you don't need the complexities of sharing a filesystem between containers.  What leads to wanting a Unix socket here?

Comment: @DavidMaze I am using docker-compose and sometimes whenever service container is recreated docker assigns it a different IP and sometimes I get a Bad Gateway I know I could assign a static IP but I want to test the UNIX domain socket, In theory, UDS should work.

Comment: You don't need the container IP addresses; Docker provides an internal DNS service, so the Compose service names like `my-api-container` are usable as host names.